# Convert a String to unicode

Tags: unicode-string

I want to convert the following below string into unicode and save the same into database. Can  someone please let me know how can I convert a string that has non ascii characters to uncode.

For example:

String s = how are you ¿cómo estás

convert it into

how are you \u??? ( non ascii characters into unicode)

Is there any Java API that does this?

Thanks,
Sai.